# Gmaps4Rails v2 - Retrieving all markers

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I have the following script to add markers on map working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({
    provider: {
      flat: false,
      noClear: false,
      zoom: 13
    }
    internal: { id: 'map' }
  },
  function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  });
</script>
```

Great! Imagine that I need to retrieve all markers on map in another function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function allMarkers() {
    //handler.getMap().markers ??
  } 
</script>
```

How can I load all markers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to manage the markers in a way which makes sense to you.

Maybe something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({
    provider: {
       flat: false,
      noClear: false,
      zoom: 13
    },
    internal: { id: 'map' }
  },
  function(){
    Gmaps.markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(Gmaps.markers);
  });

 function allMarkers() {
    return Gmaps.markers || [];
  } 
</script>
```